# how to mount a XFS filesystem in LVM volume with RAID0 having a bad disk?

Tags: linux, raid, data-recovery, lvm2

I have a small NAS with two 500GB disks in a RAID0 (JBOD) setup. (I know, I know, big mistake... as you will see...)

Now, one of the disks started to fail (Murphy is always right, isn't he...)

I took off the disks from NAS, put them in separate SATA-to-USB boxes and connected them directly to a linux laptop to do a checkup. The result was that disk#2 has bad sectors.

My question is obvious: **how do I recover data from the faulty disk?**

I assembled the array with `mdadm` in laptop, hoping to recover as much as I can (using `ddrescue` or `fsck`). But now I'm getting errors mounting the volume:

```
$ mount /dev/md1_vg/md1vol1 /media/iarray -o ro  
mount: No data available
```

I also tried:

```
$ mount /dev/md126 /media/iarray -o ro
mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'
```

This is the setup (in laptop):

```
$ lsblk 
NAME                        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE   MOUNTPOINT
[...]
sdb                           8:16   0 465,8G  0 disk   
├─sdb1                        8:17   0     2G  0 part   
└─sdb2                        8:18   0 463,8G  0 part   
  └─md126                     9:126  0 927,6G  0 linear 
    └─md1_vg-md1vol1 (dm-0) 252:0    0 927,6G  0 lvm    
sdc                           8:32   0 465,8G  0 disk   
├─sdc1                        8:33   0     2G  0 part   
└─sdc2                        8:34   0 463,8G  0 part   
  └─md126                     9:126  0 927,6G  0 linear 
    └─md1_vg-md1vol1 (dm-0) 252:0    0 927,6G  0 lvm    
sr0                          11:0    1   6,7G  0 rom
```

Since I was planning to use `ddrescue` and this tool uses a block device (not a mount point) I gave it a try:

```
$ ddrescue -f -n /dev/md1_vg/md1vol1 lvmimage logfile
GNU ddrescue 1.17
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
rescued:   498018 MB,  errsize:    498 GB,  current rate:        0 B/s
   ipos:   498018 MB,   errors:       1,    average rate:   25076 kB/s
   opos:   498018 MB,    time since last successful read:       1 s
Finished
```

Not good news: it had only rescued 498GB and had 498GB errors. Why did this happen? It is supposed to ignore errors and continue reading the device, isn't it? It seams that it has just recovered disk#1. The problem is that I must mount the whole volume to see the file system, as files may be scattered amongst both disks.

Now I'm stuck here... what am I doing wrong? Should I try to recover each disk partition separately and then assemble in a LVM volume? Has anyone succeeded in something like this?

I need to recover this disk... it has 8 years of my kids' life (photos and videos), work, university's work, my wife's work... and I just can't afford to spend €2000 in professional recovery services.

**Please help!**

(Meanwhile, I spent €220 in a new pair of WD-Red 2TB disks, 5-year warranty [whatever this means], in a RAID1 setup, of course... and I wish to recover anything I can into these)